# When Hermione got petrified, why didn't Harry hear a voice from basilisk?

Tags: harry-potter

When Hermione was at the library searching for information about the monster, she got petrified by the basilisk. Harry was just about to play quidditch at that specific moment. Why didn't Harry hear the voice from the basilisk like he did when the other students got petrified?

Comment: Why do you think that Harry was anywhere near the library when going to quidditch? Hissing of a snake (even a large one) is not much louder than a whisper... you need to be near the snake to hear it...

Answer (score 6):

He did actually.

> "Kill this time... let me rip... tear..."
>
> He shouted aloud and Ron and Hermione both jumped away from him in
> alarm.
>
> "The voice!" said Harry, -looking over his shoulder. "I just heard it
> again - didn't you?"
>
> Ron shook his head, wide-eyed. Hermione, however, clapped a hand to
> her forehead.
>
> "Harry - I think I've just understood something! I've got to go to the
> library!"

After saying this Hermione went to library where she was attacked.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  I'm not positive I understood the question correctly (though the edit helps), but I read the question as asking about when Hermione is directly attacked, which is after this.

Comment: His exact question is "Why didn't Harry hear the voice from the basilisk like he did when the other students got petrified". Harry always heard the voice when basilisk was moving inside pipes because he mostly heard voices from walls. So basilisk wasn't saying these things at the time of the attack. Harry mostly heard him all the time before any attack was about to take place in other students cases.